# Char Array in Turbo C

Tags: arrays, char, turbo-c

Okay so I have this code

```
char from;
clrscr();
printf("Enter: ");
scanf("%s", &from);
if(from == 'a' || from == 'A') {
    // blah blah code
}
```

Is there any other way or shortcut on the condition instead of using ||?

Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ASCII character set, you could mask the bit that varies between `'A'` and `'a'`:

```
if ((from | 0x20) == 'a') …
```

`toupper` is clearer and (strictly speaking) more portable, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `toupper` function:
http://www.ousob.com/ng/turboc/ng61ac1.php

```
if(toupper(from) == 'A') {
    // blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'||' means 'or' don't know if there's another shortcut but what you're doing is right. There's '&&' which means 'and' and this one could be used when you want to meet two conditions in the same conditional if.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

 char from;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%c", &from);
    if(toupper(from)=='A') {
        // blah blah code
    }
```